# Append two different types of div's to a single container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two different div with classes called "red" and "blue". By default these are hidden. I want to clone and display them into a single container called "cont". Red button appends red div's blue button appends blue div's.

```
function redCreator(word){
  var red =document.getElementsByClassName('red')[redPos];
  redPos++;
  var redClone = red.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById('cont').appendChild(redClone);
  item.style.display = 'inline';
  item.innerHTML=word;
}

function blueCreator(word){
 //same as red
}
```

Right now the red divs appear separately from blue div. **Ignoring the time and order** I clicked them

> red1|red2|red3|blue1|blue2

How do I allow the divs to display in the order I clicked them? Regardless of the class.

> red1|blue1|red2|blue2|blue3

One solution I came up with was to use a common class name and add the red/blue class later.

```
function redCreator(word){
  var item =document.getElementsByClassName('input-item')[itemPos];
  itemPos++;
  var itemClone = item.cloneNode(true);
  itemClone.className += " red";
  document.getElementById('cont').appendChild(itemClone);
  item.style.display = 'inline';
  item.innerHTML=word;

}
```

However this doesn't work as expected. CSS is messed up

Comment: You had put the tag on that states jQuery ... are you using jquery here? and what version?  I ask because there might be an easier way with jQuery, but your sample code here seems to be standard javascript and no jQuery is used.

Comment: I am using jQuery. It's not used in this specific code. Vanilla JS is preferred but if its easier with jquery then its fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Case you are looking for a pure JS solution :

HTML :

```
<div class="red input">red</div>
  <div class="blue input">blue</div>
<div id="cont">
</div>

<button onclick="redCreator('red');">RED</button>

<button onclick="blueCreator('blue');">blue</button>
```

CSS

```
.input {
  display: none;
  padding:10px;
 }
.red {
  background:red;
}
.blue {
  background:blue;
}
```

JS:

```
function redCreator(word){
  var red =document.getElementsByClassName('red')[0];
  console.log(red);
  var redClone = red.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById('cont').appendChild(redClone);
  redClone.style.display = 'inline-block';
  redClone.innerHTML=word;
}

function blueCreator(word){
 var blue =document.getElementsByClassName('blue')[0];
  var blueClone = blue.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById('cont').appendChild(blueClone);
  blueClone.style.display = 'inline-block';
  blueClone.innerHTML=word;
}
```

Just add some lines to get the numbering and you will be fine.
Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

So using jQuery (the fiddle is using 1.9.1 - but it should be forward compatible) I have put together a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/27oa1pb7/

In this - it takes contents of hidden divs and appending them in the order you click them into the "cont" container ...  using CSS, you could change the display of the divs, etc.  It uses a very basic chain of jQuery commands:

```
...
$("#reddiv").clone().show().appendTo( "#cont" )
...
```

This code is what I came up with using your description, as there is no HTML or CSS example stating exactly what you may need.

Hope this helps! 
Happy coding!